# How does imul and idiv really work 8086?

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, twos-complement, negative-number

I am trying to figure out how the imul and idiv instructions of the 8086 microprocessor work.

I know this:
1. mul and div are multiplications and division for unsigned numbers
2. imul and idiv, are also multiplications and divisions but for signed numbers

I searched all the web, and what I just wrote above, that's the only info that I've found, but written in different ways.

I have this:

```
mov AX, 0FFCEh
idiv AH
```

Because ah it's a byte, AL=AX/AH (the result) and AH=remainder

After the instruction I get **AX=0032h**, obviously 0 remainder, and the result 32. Can somebody explain how it got to this result ? I need to know how to explain how the instruction works (bit by bit).

Same goes with the imul instruction.

I have:

```
mov AX, 0FF10h
imul AL
```

Because AL is a byte, the result of the multiplication will be saved into AX. After the execution of the imul instruction **AX=0100h**, why isn't it F100h ?

I don't how the CPU actually does mul, div, imul and idiv. If somebody could illustrate for me the differences, would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: The description for `IMUL r/m8` is `AX <- AL * r/m byte`. So `imul AL` multiplies `AL` with `AL` and stores the product in `AX`. In your case `AL` contains `10h`, so the product will be `10h * 10h == 100h`.

Comment: You are using IDIV, it interprets its operands as signed values.  So it is 0FFCEh / 0FFh = -50 / -1 = 50 = 32h.

Comment: Please be more clear what are you asking. Do you want to know more about bit-shifting used to implement these instructions in hardware? Or do you want to know more about registers used in these operations even when they are not explicitly written in the instruction? I would like to help, but really don't understand which part is problematic for you.

Comment: Take a look at this http://fleder44.net/312/notes/10MultDiv/index.html it

Answer (score 3):

## idiv part of answer

```
mov AX, FFCE
idiv AH
```

**AX**=FFCE

**AH**=FF

definition of negative is that their highest ranked bit equals 1, so 
FFCE is negative,

because
**1**111 1111 1100 1110

and processor cannot work with negatives, 
we need to have positive, that means we negate this number (or processor does this based on highest ranked bit automaticallly)

```
NEG FFCE
```

or

```
    1111 1111 1100 1110 => 
=>  0000 0000 0011 0001 +1 =>
=>  0000 0000 0011 0010 =>
=>  0032h
```

then next - AH register is FF - also negative and 
we need positive version, we negate

```
    1111 1111 =>
=>  0000 0000 +1 =>
=>  0000 0001 =>
=>  01h
```

then when all numbers are positive, we calculate division

32h div 1h, 0h remainder => AL, 32h result => AH

both are negative that means that result is positive and needs no more conversions.

## imul part of answer

```
mov AX, FF10
imul AL
```

**AL**=10h

imul/mul uses AL when argument is 8bit (which it is)

so imul AL is same as

```
AL * AL => 10h * 10h => 0100h = AX
```

## imul part of answer extended

```
mov AX, FF10
imul AH
```

**AH**=FF

**AL**=10h

so now we have AL * AH => AX

AL = 10h

AH = FF which is negative, we need positive, we negate and get => 01h

multiplication of positives

`10h * 01h => 0010h`

but as only one of them was negative, we have to negate result,
do not lose starting zeros, or your answer will be incorrect

```
0010h => FFEF +1 => FFF0 = AX
```

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's binary multiplication article explains the bit-level details, and [has a section about signed multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier#More_advanced_approach:_signed_integers).  You could find similar bit-level details for division.

---

But like Hans says, you don't really need to understand the details to solve this problem.  You do need to know that unlike add/sub, the bitwise operation of mul and div are different for 2's complement integers vs. unsigned integers, not just the interpretation of the result.  Fun fact: for multiplication, [the lower half of the full-width result is the same for mul and imul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in).

So the instruction reference manual's description of the instruction operation is all you need, plus an understanding that e.g. the [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of -1 is 0xFF.  (See http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/, or Intel's original PDF: links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki)

Interpret the bits in each operand the same way the instruction will, and do the math "normally".  e.g.

```
AX = 0xFFCE      =>   -2^16 + 0xFFCE = -0x32 = -50
AH = 0xFF        =>   -1

-50 / -1 = 50,  no remainder
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is partially spelled out in comments.

```
mov AX, 0FFCEh
idiv AH
```

divides FFCE by FF. Thankfully this is signed division or this would raise an error.

Multiply is far easier:

```
mov AX, 0FF10h
imul AL
```

will store the result of AL * AL in AX.

Beware of larger than byte multiply and divide; they use the DX register as well.